# Google ml kit object and face detection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mlkit

I am working on an application where i have to detect objects over the face. How do i do this...
I have created app for face detection and it works fine.

How do i do both the detections using same camera. Only one button i have which opens camera where face is getting detected.

````
   if (!_canProcess) return;
   if (_isBusy) return;
   _isBusy = true;
   setState(() {
     _text = '';
   });
   final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);
   if (inputImage.metadata?.size != null &&
       inputImage.metadata?.rotation != null) {
     final painter = FaceDetectorPainter(
       faces,
       inputImage.metadata!.size,
       inputImage.metadata!.rotation,
       _cameraLensDirection,
     );
     _customPaint = CustomPaint(painter: painter);
   } else {
     String text = 'Faces found: ${faces.length}\n\n';
     for (final face in faces) {
       text += 'face: ${face.boundingBox}\n\n';
     }
     _text = text;
     // TODO: set _customPaint to draw boundingRect on top of image
     _customPaint = null;
   }
   _isBusy = false;
   if (mounted) {
     setState(() {});
   }
 }
}```
````